# FreeNAS: Host name/name mismatch for smbd

Tags: logs, smb, freenas

My FreeNAS box has been acting weird for a while. My log file is filled with the following:

```
Mar 21 06:57:46 freenas smbd[79405]:   STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connectionsmatchname: host name/name mismatch: 192.168.0.249 != (NULL)

Mar 21 06:57:46 freenas smbd[79405]: [2015/03/21 06:57:46.036921,  0] ../source3/lib/util_sock.c:1199(get_remote_hostname)
```

I cannot recall for how long this has been the way, but I thought I fixed it a couple of days ago and forgot to check my logs. Obviously I hadn't fixed it.

The issue revolves around host name lookup, which can be disabled via the FreeNAS interface for CIFS. Disabling this solves the issue described above but does not solve the original question: "Why haven't this appeared for as long as I've been *running the share*?". I have not changed my settings regarding DNS on my LAN but this issue first occurred only a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: What did you do for fixing it?

Comment: I haven't, I'm here looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors regarding hostname lookups means you do not have DNS configured for your LAN. To get rid of these messages you have to uncheck Hostname lookups on the CIFS settings.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did find this idea on FreeNAS's bug site as well but have yet to confirm it. However, this has not been issue before and I have no idea why it has stopped working. Do you know of a way one can dive further into this?

Comment: I think if you leave it like this, it won't be a problem. Totally benign.

Comment: Well, that might be the case, but it doesn't explain why it stopped working all of a sudden. :(

Comment: You have to provide more info or edit your question.

Comment: This just hit me. "benign" is relative, it caused permanent high CPU load when any client was connected. High being > 50%. DNS names from my local DNS server are working perfectly (nslookup was doing fine), though disabling hostname lookup did fix it... eventually after restarting the SMB client. SMB+FreeNAS ...